# How to configure expo to allow password managers to associate an app to a web domain

Tags: android, expo, passwords, autofill

I am trying to get password managers to provide items that correspond to our web domain. It works fine for iOS by having the following configuration

```
"associatedDomains": [
    "webcredentials:my.domain.com"
],
```

in the app.json and providing a the file /.well-known/apple-app-site-association.json on the web domain.  We have tried to provide an /.well-known/assetlinks.json file for android with the following content:

```
[
    {
        "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "web",
            "site": "https://my.domain.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "com.domain.my",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["..."]
        }
    }
]
```

and add an intent filter like

```
           "intentFilters": [
                {
                    "action": "VIEW",
                    "autoVerify": true,
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "scheme": "https",
                            "host": "my.domain.com"
                        }
                    ],
                    "category": ["DEFAULT", "BROWSABLE"]
                }
            ]
```

to the app.json configuration. However, it is not working on android. Anyone has experience with configuring that for android? Help would be much appreciated.